# Why my vue.js table won't render?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to render table using vue.js but I have a lot of problems. I do not know how to render it all using v-for. I tried almost everything.. In console everything looks okay, but table is clear. How to do it correctly?

```
<template>
        <table class="table table-striped ">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th></th>
              <th>Name</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr v-for="users in usr" :is="users" :usr="users">
                <td>{{usr.name}}</td>
                <td>{{usr.name}}</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: [
            'user',
            'users'
        ],
        data: function () {
          return {
            usr: [],
            }
        },
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Your `v-for` is incomprehensible. `usr` is an empty array that never gets populated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what kind of data you're using, but let's just assume you have an array of user objects in `users`

```
<tr v-for="user in users" :key="user.name">
    <td>{{user.name}}</td>
    <td>{{user.name}}</td>
</tr>
```

This will loop over each `user` object in `users`. `user` here is an alias, meaning it can be anything.

```
<tr v-for="dumbledore in users" :key="dumbledore.name">
    <td>{{dumbledore.name}}</td>
    <td>{{dumbledore.name}}</td>
</tr>
```

Will work